Distance function related to tiled hex plane
Imagine having a plane tiled with regular hexagons. Then the question is: Given a point within the plane how far away is the nearest center of one of the hexagons? A picture for context:
At first we can easily find a function, which describes all the given centers of the hexagons.
$$
M_a = \begin{vmatrix}a\frac{3}{2} & 0 \\a \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & a \sqrt{3}   \end{vmatrix}
\\ \vec{X}=M_a( \lambda\hat{i}+\mu\hat{j}) \qquad \forall \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{Z}
$$
Using the floor function, we can extend the domain to the real numbers:
$$
\vec{X_f}=M_a(\lfloor{\lambda + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\hat{i}+\lfloor{\mu + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\hat{j}) \qquad \forall \lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}
$$
If we now take a point $r$, we get:
$$
\vec{d_f}=\vec{X_f}-\vec{r} 
$$
This is where i first ran into some problems, because i wasnt able find the minimum of the given function $\vec{d_f}$, using calculus. Instead I tried the following:
$$
\vec{X}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}a\frac{3}{2}\\a \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \end{pmatrix}+\mu \begin{pmatrix}0\\ a \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$ \vec{d}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}a\frac{3}{2}\\a \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \end{pmatrix}+\mu \begin{pmatrix}0\\ a \sqrt{3}\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}x_r \\y_r \end{pmatrix}
\\
$$
Now let $\lambda,\mu$ be real variables, then there always exist a point $r$ such that $\vec{d}=0$. This obviously happens when both of the following conditions are satisfied:
$$
I.a\lambda_1\frac{3}{2}=x_r\\
II.a\lambda_1\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+a\mu_1\sqrt{3}=y_r
$$
Solving the equation system, we get:
$$
\lambda_1=\frac{2}{3}\frac{x_r}{a}
\qquad
\mu_1=\frac{y_r\sqrt{3}-x_r}{3a}
$$
So our intersection point $E$ obviously lies at:
$$
E(\lambda_1,\mu_1)
$$
Using this and the fact that no point can be further than $1$ from the closest center, we can approximate in which region we find the necessary argument $R(\lambda_2,\mu_2)$for our function $\vec{d_f}$ in order to determain the distance $min(|\vec{d_f}|)$.
$$
g: (x-\lambda_1)^2+(y-\mu_1)^2\leq1
\\
R \in D_g
$$
We now could check the up to $5$ Points $(x_1,y_1) \in \mathbb{N}^2 \cap D_g$ using our distance function $|\vec{d}|$. But this result is very unsatisfying as this just allows you to numerically calculate the distance to the nearest center. How would one go about determining this without numerical methods?

This hexagonal grid and its underlying triangular grid can also be considered as a rhomboidal grid with rhombi (made of two equilateral triangles) like $PQRS$ on Fig. 3. We are going to show that the issue is to find the rhombus in which is situated the given point $M$.
Barycentric coordinates $[p,q,r]$ (shortened into "b.c.") with respect to "basis triangle"
$$A=(\sqrt{3}/2, 1/2), \ \ B=(0,1), \ \ C(0,0)$$
have been used. Please note that these points are represented in your figure ; for the sake of simplicity, I have chosen $a=1$.
The following (Matlab) program is a "proof of concept" showing (Fig. 1) that whatever the position of the given point $M$, the closest point is found. Explanations and correspondence with Matlab program and Fig. 3 are given below.
 clear all;close all;
 a=4.5;
 plot(a*[1,0,0],a*[0,0,1],'k');axis equal tight;hold on;
 i=complex(0,1);
 k=1/sqrt(3);
 om=(sqrt(3)+i)/2;
 b2c=@(z)(om*(real(z)+1)+i*(imag(z)-1)); % from barycentric to cartesian
 for n=1:10000
    x=a*rand;y=a*rand;Z=x+i*y; % random point M
    p=2*k*x-1;q=-k*x+y+1;%r=-k*x-y+1; % barycentric coord. of M w.r.t. ABC
    P=floor(p)+i*floor(q); % lower left point
    R=P+[0,1,i,1+i]; % will be transformed into rhombus with vertices R(1)... R(4)
    V=b2c(R); % back to cartesian coordinates
    Li=abs(Z-V); % list of distances to the 4 points
    [~,J]=sort(Li); 
    S=V(J(1)); % selecting the vertex with shortest dist.
    plot([Z,S]); 
 end;


Fig. 1 : 10000 random points "attracted" to the nearest point of the lattice, naturaly generating a hexagonal pattern.
One must be aware that for a point exterior to triangle $ABC$, one or two of its coordinates are negative as can be seen on Fig. 2 (adapted from one of my texts dealing with something else : Padovan spiral) :

Fig. 2 : Reference triangle in pink : the b.c. of its vertices are (of course) $A[1,0,0],B[0,1,0],C[0,0,1]$. Whatever the point chosen in the plane, the sum of its (normalized) b.c. is always 1. How can the lines be interpreted ? For example the set of points having their first b.c. $p$ equal to $1$ is the horizontal line passing through $A$.
Explanations : An important feature of barycentric coordinates $[p,q,r]$ is as follows : restricting them for example to the first two $(p,q)$, they plainly behave like cartesian coordinates with respect to slant axes as can be understood with the cyan and green lines on Fig. 3. On this figure, the rhombus containing a given point $M$ with b.c. $[p,q,r]$ has its lower left vertex $P$ with b.c. $[p',q',r']$ obtained by taking the integer parts : $p'=\lfloor p \rfloor$ and $q'=\lfloor q \rfloor$, with $r'=1-p'-q'$.

Fig. 3 : Consider the case of point $M=(2.1;2.9)$ with b.c. $[2.42, 1.69, -3.11]$ with respect to reference triangle $ABC$. The program finds rhombus $PQRS$. $P=V(1), Q=V(2), R=V(3), S=V(4)$, lower left vertex $P$ having b.c. $[\lfloor 2.42 \rfloor,\lfloor 1.69 \rfloor,1-\lfloor 1.42 \rfloor-\lfloor 2.69 \rfloor]=[2,1,-2]$, where $\lfloor ... \rfloor$ is the "integer part function". It remains to compute 4 distances and find the smallest one, and the winner is... vertex $S$.
Remarks :

There are hopefuly other ways to reach the same result, bypassing for example the use of b.c.

Your hexagonal cells are the Voronoi cells associated with Delaunay triangulation of the plane by equilateral triangles such as $ABC$.



Does $r(u')+r(v')+r(w')=1$ ?

@Empy2 No, you are right, there is something I must correct in my explanations : instead of $r(w')$, I must write $(1-r(u')-r(v'))$ (even if In fact, as I say, we don't need $r(w')$).

Doesn't the entire centre upside-down quarter-triangle inside triangle $ABC$ rounds to $(0,0,0)$? but the nearest centre isn't the same.

@Empy I just introduced a graphical representation in order that barycentric coordinates with negative weights can be understood. I am going to think about your last comment. I don't think I will have time this evening because it's already late.

Here is an interesting site for working on / playing with hexagonal grids.

@Empy I have now a method which works in $100$% of cases. Thanks for having pointed to my mistakes.

See also this question and its answer by Aaron Meyerowitz.

You need three measurements, one for each direction.
$$(a,b,c)=(\lceil\frac{2y}{\sqrt3}\rceil,
\lceil x-\frac y{\sqrt3}\rceil,
\lceil -x-\frac y{\sqrt3}\rceil)
$$
For all the lattice points $a+b+c=0$, and all three numbers are equal $\pmod3$.
The points within any one hexagon give six different $(a,b,c)$, one for each triangle that makes up the hexagon.
For all non-lattice points, $a+b+c$ is $1$ or $2$, so two numbers are equal $\pmod3$ and the other is different.  If the sum is $1$, subtract $1$ from the different one.  If the sum is $2$, subtract $1$ from both the equal $\pmod3$ ones.
For the points that are the intersection of three hexagons, $a+b+c=0$ and they are all different $\pmod3$  Add $1$ to one and subtract $1$ from another so they are now equal $\pmod3$
You now have $(a',b',c')$ with $a'+b'+c'=0$.  The lattice point is
$$(\frac{b'-c'}2,\frac{a'\sqrt3}2)$$
